# google people.api, people.getBatchGet, how to build the resourceNames List?

Tags: vba, google-people-api

with one resourceName this code works fine

```
    strTmp = resources(1)
    Set web_HTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Repeat2:
    web_Url_AllResources = "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:batchGet"
    web_HTTP.Open "GET", web_Url_AllResources & "?" & _
        "access_token=" & Token & "&" & _
        "key=" & ApiKey & "&" & _
        "resourceNames=" & strTmp & "&" & _
        "personFields=" & "names,addresses,organizations,memberships"
```

the value in strTmp is people/c1546047072727163997

If I wish to get more than one resource with

```
strTmp = resources(1) & "," & resources(2)
```

i get an error code 400: invalid argument, ResourceName false

I don't know how to build an valid request list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide a `resourceNames` parameter for each resource person you want information about. Because the ResourceName you provided (something like `people/c12345,people/c123456`) does not exist, you get this error.

The URI to request in this case would have to be:

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:batchGet?resourceNames=people/c12345&resourceNames=people/c123456&{other-fields}
```

So in this case, you would have to do the following:

```
    strTmp = resources(1)
    strTmpBis = resources(2)
    Set web_HTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Repeat2:
    web_Url_AllResources = "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:batchGet"
    web_HTTP.Open "GET", web_Url_AllResources & "?" & _
        "access_token=" & Token & "&" & _
        "key=" & ApiKey & "&" & _
        "resourceNames=" & strTmp & "&" & _
        "resourceNames=" & strTmpBis & "&" & _
        "personFields=" & "names,addresses,organizations,memberships"
```

I'd suggest you to test calls about which you have doubts with [apis-explorer](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet?apix=true) and/or with [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

#### Reference:

- [people.getBatchGet](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet)

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: I would never have gotten there. Thank you